# Why won't AngularJS run on Node.JS server?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I have a angular based app, which contains the 4 folders:
- CSS (contains CSS files)
- JS (contains controller folder and the app.js)
- Views (contains the html files)

I cannot run the app.js in a node server, the error I keep on getting is

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

And when I click on just the html files it shows only text and the css is not applied. How do I go about running this type of angular app/

Comment: I know angular2+ has server-side rendering, but i suspect that's not what you're doing and you just don't understand what you're trying to do... you shouldn't need to run that code in that way as a node app...

Comment: I am simply trying to run the app locally. From my understanding ( as I am new to angular) you should simply click the html page and the link between the html and the js should allow the page to run locally. I have a apache localhost up and when I spawn the html from the host  result is the same, the app doesn't run. There doesn't seem to be broken linkage to css pages. What I am asking is how to run app.js. I am so far treating it like a node app, and trying to get it running where the app.js runs the html files like node app would.  I just want to run the app.

Comment: You include it into an html file and load up the html file in a browser. No node needed/required. You do however need a webserver (apache, nginx, iis, node.js, whatever you want to use.)

Comment: Interesting, from my understanding, it is NOT treated as a node app. If the index.html is spawned into the browser, it run the app.js (which controls the controllers js and the views html). Am I understanding it properly? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Angular.js is not a node application. It's a client-side framework. The only thing it uses node for is NPM and build processes for minifying/concatenating the code, all of which only happen in development, not production.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the clarification @KevinB!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to include first the AngularJs's file/cdn and then your app.js file. You probably need to send all the files that are involved in your page like css, js and so on. If you post more code about your server-side application we may help you.